# How to get all distinct elements per key in DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have the following DataFrame:

```
scala> val dataset = Seq((0, "hello"), (0, "world"), (0, "hello"), (1, "foo"), (1, "bar")).toDF("id", "text")
dataset: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, text: string]

scala> dataset.show()
+---+-----+
| id| text|
+---+-----+
|  0|hello|
|  0|world|
|  0|hello|
|  1|  foo|
|  1|  bar|
+---+-----+
```

How do I get the distinct `text` for each `id`? I.e., I want to do something like:

```
dataset.groupBy("id").agg(distinct('text))
```

Do I have to create a `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`? I ultimately want a list for each `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `collect_set`:

```
dataset.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set($"text")).show
+---+-----------------+
| id|collect_set(text)|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|       [bar, foo]|
|  0|   [world, hello]|
+---+-----------------+
```